# Installing Anaconda on Git Bash and trying conda activate results in repeated CommandNotFoundErrors

Tags: visual-studio-code, anaconda, git-bash

I've recently refreshed my Git Bash and Anaconda installation, and I am trying to run Git Bash from within VSCode with Anaconda. The issue is that whenever I open the integrated terminal from within VSCode, the terminal does not show up with a (base) tag and when I run `conda activate`, it returns the CommandNotFoundError:

```
If using 'conda activate' from a batch script, change your
invocation to 'CALL conda.bat activate'.

To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - cmd.exe
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

I have followed the instructions with `conda init bash` and restarted the shell, but it keeps giving this error. I've seen a couple other articles, but most of them are outdated and the others have no solutions that work. Anaconda still works on external Git Bash when I don't use the integrated terminal. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

When you've run `conda init bash` it probably created a `~/.bash_profile` file. If you want the git bash terminal from VS Code to know about it, then do the following on a git bash terminal:

```bsh
echo '. ${HOME}/.bash_profile' >> ~/.bashrc
```

That adds whichever command anaconda added to the `.bash_profile` also into the `.bashrc` (which is executed for interactive non-login shells - and that's what VS Codes gets), whereas `.bash_profile` is for login shells (which is what git bash runs everytime a new terminal opens). There's more information about [the differences between `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` on another SE question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/51038).

*Note*: If you have experience with these files, then you could copy the bits from `.bash_profile` that you need instead of sourcing all the commands you may have in there.

Comment: Thank you very much! Works for me!

Comment: Wow, this was really anoying me. It was a simple solution. I didn't know that git bash didn't execute .bash_profile. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can run source activate base to get it up and running, can't get the bash script to run in VSCode using bash terminal tho.  If someone finds out plz halp....

more refs...

https://www.anaconda.com/conda-4-6-release/